# Find Available Virtual Machine Sizes in Azure Subscription Using ARM Powershell or Portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I'm looking for a Powershell Azure **Resource Manager** (not Classic) version of [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285470/azure-virtual-machine-size-information-on-powershell#)

I am trying to find the available VM Sizes per subscription, not per region.  I have two Azure subscriptions, one from MSDN, and one not.  The Subscription from MSDN allows me to create DS2 v2 VMs, but the other one does not allow me to create any DS2 machines (even though I am also creating these machines in WestUS), so I have to use an L4.  Apparently, this has something to do with what Microsoft calls a "tier".

I would like to know how to find all the available VM sizes in a subscription using the new ARM Powershell commands, if possible.

Alternatively, if there is a way to see a list of available VM sizes per subscription in the portal, that would also work.

I have tried to get this info using the following script:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionID
Get-AzureRoleSize
```

But I get an error message ("No default description has been designated").  I suspect that this is because I am mixing ARM and ACM Powershell commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two Azure subscriptions, one from MSDN, and one not. The
> Subscription from MSDN allows me to create DS2 v2 VMs, but the other
> one does not allow me to create any DS2 machines (even though I am
> also creating these machines in WestUS), so I have to use an L4.

By default, Azure supports 20 cores per region. You could use `Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location yourregion` to check.

[image]

If you want to raise the limit or quota above the Default Limit, [open an online customer support request at no charge](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-limits-quotas-increase-requests/). The limits can't be raised above the Maximum Limit value.

You also could see a list of available VM sizes per subscription in the portal.

> Subscription-->Usage + quotas

[image]

Also, you could refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983698/azure-vm-size-not-available/41995837#41995837).

Update:

If your cores does not reach all limit, it seems DsV2 SKU is not avilaibe in your subscription, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/sku-series-unavailable) to solve this issue.

Comment: This is not a problem with quotas or regions.  Using my first subscription, I can create as many DS2 v2 machines as I want in WestUS;  my second subscription does not give me the option of creating DS2 v2 in WestUs.  It shows DS2 v2 size as greyed out when I try to create a machine in the portal, so I have to use an L4 instead.  Running the Get-AzureRmUsage command shows that I am using 0 DSv2 Family cores with a limit of 350.     I am looking for a way to tell me which sizes I am allowed to use in the 2nd subscription.

Comment: Hi,  do you check all Cores?

Comment: When I try to create a DS2 v2 using PowerShell in the second subscription, I get this error message "The requested tier for resource is currently not available in location for subscription."  I can use PowerShell to create an L4 in this subscription no problem.  Hence, I need to know what machine sizes I can create in this subscription.

Comment: If you don't reach all cores in your subscription, it seems the DS2V2 SKU is not available WestUS, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/sku-series-unavailable) to solve this issue.

Comment: Total Regional Cores is 8 with a limit of 350

Comment: Yes, it does not reach the limit, I have the similar issue. You could refer to this [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/30b0809c-b70f-4565-b281-98f7cc9ff69d/north-europe-not-available-for-virutal-machine-deployment-in-msdn-subscription?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138879/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-greg-thatcher).